# Accessing Excel's Object Model from Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I have excel as an activeX object in javascript.  I seem to be missing something with reards to how to interact with the object model from there. My watch window shows the value of the "Value" property of the range I am trying to pull data from as "undefined" when I try to assign "range.Value" to an array.

Unfortunately I am unable to update the outdated browsers on my machine at work so I cannot upload pictures.

My script:

```
function open_files(A, B, C) 
{ 
 var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
 excel.Visible=true;
 excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
 var wbA = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(A).value);
 var wbB = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(B).value);
 var wbC = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(C).value);

 excel.EnableEvents = false;
 excel.ScreenUpdating = false;
 excel.Calculation = -4135 //xlCalculationManual enumeration;

 var wb_collection = [wbA, wbB, wbC];

 excel.Application.Run("'" + wbA.name + "'" + '!update_links');

 var CLIN_list = [wbA.Sheets("Control Form").Range("B62:B141").value(1)]

 for (i = 0; i = CLIN_list.length; i++)
 { 
  if (CLIN_list(i) > 0)
  {
   var CLIN_list_count = i
  }
 }

 var decrement_range_start = wbA.Sheets("Fee & Decrement Table").Range("AJ14")

 //for (i = 0; i < 80; i++){
   //Sheets("Fee & Decrement Table").Cells(decrement_range_start.column+i


 // Model Setup for VBA
 wbA.Sheets("CONTROL FORM").Activate
 wbA.Sheets("CONTROL FORM").OLEObjects("TextBox21").Object.Text = wbB.fullname
 wbA.Sheets("CONTROL FORM").OLEObjects("TextBox22").Object.Text = wbC.fullname

 excel.Application.Run("'" + wbA.name + "'" + '!Run_JPO');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on another forum.  A Range cannot be assigned directly to a js array, it has to be converted.  The line below works to fill my CLIN_list variable.

```
var CLIN_list = new VBArray(wbA.Sheets("Control Form").Range("B62:B141").value).toArray();
```